# How does adding a non clustered index to a table result in an index seek operation?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table with 3 columns: `ID, FirstName, Salary`.

Now I have a clustered index on ID and when I execute this query

```
select * from table where FirstName = 'a'
```

I get the result using a clustered indexed scan and asks me to add a non clustered index on the first name.

When I add a non clustered index on the `FirstName` then I get the result as a result of a `Index Seek`.

I don't understand why an index seek? Since the non clustered index does not sort the data shouldn't it be an scan?

Comment: if you are querying (lot more than write) records based on firstname, then an index on that column is optimal. the result that you get would get would be a combination of seeks, Index Seek first i believe

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: "Index Scan retrieves all the rows from the table. Index Seek retrieves selective rows from the table" so when you have <where FirstName = 'a'> sorting or not sorting doesnt matter, index seek kicks in.. is that not your question or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: Index scan will also retrieve selective rows.  The difference between scan and seek is that scan will scan the entire table while seek will check for the indexes and only scan the relevant page in the table.

Comment: If the number of rows matched by your criteria (`FirstName = 'a'`) is sufficiently small, then the query optimizer will use an **index seek** in your non-clustered index to find the row(s) that match that critiera, and then a **Key lookup** into the main data pages to get all the data columns (since you're using a `SELECT * ..`). It's up to the optimizer to decide when a index seek+key lookup is more efficient than a clustered index scan. It depends mostly on selectivity - if your criteria matches too many rows, a clustered index scan will occur instead

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for your comments. How will the optimizer come to know how many records will be retrieved?

Comment: @Ckv: that's the magic of **statistics**. SQL Server keeps statistics about what kind of data distribution there is in certain columns. Those help the optimizer "know" (or at least "guess") how many rows there will be affected by a query.

Comment: @marc_s: I think it makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of rows matched by your criteria (`FirstName = 'a'`) is sufficiently small, then the SQL Server query optimizer will use an `index seek` in your non-clustered index to find the row(s) that match that criteria, and then in a second step use a `Key lookup` into the main data pages to get all the data columns (since you're using a `SELECT * ..`).

It's up to the optimizer to decide when a index seek + key lookup is more efficient than a clustered index scan. It depends mostly on selectivity - if your criteria matches too many rows, a clustered index scan will occur instead.

The "magic" that enables the query optimizer to make such decisions is the **statistics** about the data and data distribution that SQL Server keeps - both for indexes, as well as for additional, selective columns in your tables.

And if the statistics are out of date (since you've done a lot of updating and possibly deleting), then it's entirely possible that the query optimizer will use inefficient / unsuitable execution plans. This is one of the major performance issues - always make sure that your statistics are well maintained and up to date! (by using e.g. a maintenance plan that updates the statistics every night or every week - depending on how frequently you manipulate large chunks of data).